# Return null in case of empty object in C#

Tags: c#

I try this statement to check if SSN is not empty return the value in SSNstr otherwise return null. But this is returning me error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when SSN is empty.

```
  Model.DocumentData dt = new Model.DocumentData();     
 dt.SSNstr = (dt.SSNstr == null ? null :(string)individual.XPathSelectElement("Individual/SSN")).Insert(5,"-").Insert(3,"-");
```

this is dt class:

```
      [DataMember]
      public string SSNstr = string.Empty;
```

Please attention here I know how to check null value but I like to do it in same line of code.
As I have so many fields like this that I need to check I prefer to check in 1 line of the code or change something in dt class that take care of it.

Comment: either dt or individual is null check them.  like  dt!=null && dt.SSNstr==null...something like that

Comment: Also, `XPathSelectElement` cound be returning `null` (causing the chained `Insert` to throw an exception).

Comment: If it is `null` you cannot do an `Insert` on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried debugging this problem?

Comment: You need check if SSNstr is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Null and "empty string" are two different things. Make your check with `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

At the end of that, the result of your XPath query might be empty. Why don't you break that up into a few lines?

Addendum: It really looks like your XPath query result is empty. You're working on the assumption that it will not be empty. Do you have that assurance? When you're programming, don't trust anyone. Including yourself.

Comment: Thanks just because it is too many fields like 50, I wanted to make each in 1 line so make it less code and cleaner. Si it any possibility I can check all in this line?

Comment: @Alma, let me put it this way: Whether it's one field or 500, you're not saving time if your expression stands on one line but is too complex to debug. Visually, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: If "fewer lines = cleaner code" were true, we'd all be posting serious questions on codegolf.SE

Comment: @Alma you can always extract a single line method to place in all 50 spots once you have the method logic complete.

Answer (score 2):

Check your parentheses.

If `dt.SSNstr` is `null`, the expression is not returning `null`, it is returning `(null).Insert(5,"-").Insert(3,"-")` which causes the error. You can't insert anything into `null`.

One solution would be to write

```
dt.SSNstr = dt.SSNstr == null ? null :(string)individual.XPathSelectElement("Individual/SSN").Insert(5,"-").Insert(3,"-");
```

but then if would be better to have

```
if (dt.SSNstr!=null)
  dt.SSNstr =(string)individual.XPathSelectElement("Individual/SSN").Insert(5,"-").Insert(3,"-");
```

otherwise you're assigning null to a variable that is already null.

Edit: As the other answers say, you should check for `IsNullOrEmpty`, not just equal to `null`. You start out with `string.Empty`, but later you assign `null` to it.

Comment: I tried different way of putting parentheses but it producing error. can you say what should I change?

Comment: Remove the first `(` and the second `)`). I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`dt` might be null in this case. I would check if that object actually has a value. You would need to instantiate `dt`, then you can set the value of `dt.SSNstr`.

Comment: I instantiate  dt as  Model.DocumentData dt = new Model.DocumentData(); and ssn as   [DataMember]
        public string SSNstr= string.Empty;

Answer (score 1):

Per your edit, you can simply do like

```
    dt.SSNstr = ((individual.XPathSelectElement("Individual/SSN") as string) == null) ? null : (individual.XPathSelectElement("Individual/SSN") as string).Insert(5,"-").Insert(3,"-");
```

Comment: @Alma, that's because of extra parenthesis `(`. edited the answer; should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

var test = "";

var a = string.IsNullOrEmpty(test) ? null : test;

I hope it´s Helps.

Comment: `XPathSelectElement` returns an `XElement` that does not have an `Insert` method.  You need a `.Value` before the first `Insert`.

Comment: You're right, I copied his example of it. I changed to a simple example. TKS